# Show/hide div on radio button and change form action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form action ="one.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="cardType" id="one" class="css-checkbox" value="db">
<input type="radio" name="cardType" id="two" class="css-checkbox" value="cc">

<div id="a">Hi</div>

<div id="b">Hellow</div>

</form>
```

I have a form in which there are two radio buttons and two divs.If I selected radio button with id=one then div with id="a" shud be shown and other div will be hidden and form action will be one.php. and if I select radio button with id="two",div with id="b" will be shown and form action changes to "two.php"..How can this be done using jquery or javascript.Any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form id="myForm" action ="one.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="cardType" id="one" class="css-checkbox" value="db" checked>
<input type="radio" name="cardType" id="two" class="css-checkbox" value="cc">

<div id="a">Hi</div>

<div id="b">Hellow</div>

</form>

css:
  #b{
     display:none;  
  }  


Script

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".css-checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == "one") {
                $('#a').show();
                $('#b').hide();
                $("#myForm").attr('action','one.php');
            } else {
                $('#a').hide();
                $('#b').show();
                $("#myForm").attr('action','two.php');
            }
        });

    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W62zr/)

Comment: None of the other answers are changing the action but this. Well done =)... Only this is not showing the relevant div back :P

Comment: I will test this and come back :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').hide()
    $(".css-checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "one") {
            $('#a').fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut()
            $("form").attr('action','one.php');
        } else {
            $('#b').fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut()
            $("form").attr('action','two.php');
        }
    });

 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VVQVF/2/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('input[type=radio].css-checkbox').click(function(){
    if (this.id=="one"){
        $('div#a').show();
        $('div#b').hide();
        $('form').attr('action','one.php');
    }
    else {
         $('div#a').hide();
        $('div#b').show();
        $('form').attr('action','two.php');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w7PS3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw8xf/)

```
jQuery("[name='cardType']").click(function(){
   var divs = $(this).parent().find(">div");
    divs.hide();
    if(this.id === 'one'){
        $("#a").show();
    }else{
        $("#b").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function () {

        $('input[name=cardType]').click(function () {
            var id_checked = $('input[name=cardType]:radio:checked').attr('id');
            if (id_checked == 'one') {
                $('#a').show();
                $('#b').hide();
            } else if (id_checked == 'two') {
                $('#a').hide();
                $('#b').show();
            }
            $('form').attr('action', id_checked + '.php');
        });     

    });
```